# C#WPF Antlr4.13 questions about grammar rules

Tags: c#, antlr4

Below is my grammar rules file content

```
grammar selector;
options {
    language = CSharp;
}

Decimal: '-'?[0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)?;
NoCharDecimal:'-'?([0-9]+)('.'[0-9]+)?|'-'?([0-9]+)?('.'[0-9]+);
decimal:Decimal;
noCharDecimal:NoCharDecimal;
Int:'-'?[0-9]+;
int:Int;
NoCharInt:[0-9]+;
DefaultInt:'-'?[0-9]+;
bool:'true'|'false';
MarkValue:'!'?['-'_+.a-zA-Z0-9]+?;
NameValue:'!'?['-'_+.a-zA-Z0-9]+?|'!'?'"'.*?'"';
TypeValue:'!'?'#'?'minecraft:'?[a-z_]+;
FileReferrerValue:'!'?[./_'-'a-z0-9]+':'?[./_'-'a-z0-9]+;
StringValue:'"'.*?'"';
StringKey:[a-z]+|'"'[a-z]+'"';
stringValue:StringValue;
stringKey:StringKey;
Path:~[ `~!@#$%^&*()=+\\|;'",<>?]+;
entitySelector: selectorType selectorParameters?;
selectorType: '@a' | '@p' | '@s' | '@e' | '@r';
selectorParameters:'['parameter(','parameter?)*']';
parameter: doubleKey decimal
|doubleIntervalKey decimalInterval
|intIntervalKey intInterval
|gamemode gamemodeValue
|advancements advancementsValue
|scores scoresValue
|noCharintKey int
|mark markValue
|name nameValue
|type typeValue
|fileReferrer fileReferrerValue
|jsonKey jsonValue
|sort sortValue;

doubleKey: 'x='|'y='|'z='|'dx='|'dy='|'dz=';
doubleIntervalKey:'distance='|'x_rotation='|'y_rotation=';
intIntervalKey:'level=';
noCharintKey:'limit=';
gamemode:'gamemode=';
jsonKey:'nbt=';
fileReferrer:'predicate=';
advancements:'advancements=';
scores:'scores=';
mark:'tag='|'team=';
name:'name=';
type:'type=';
sort:'sort=';
advancementPath:Path;
scorePath:Path;

jsonValue: object | array;
object: '{' (pair (',' pair)*)? '}';
pair: stringKey ':' value;
array: '[' (value (',' value)*)? ']';
value: stringValue | decimal | object | array | 'true' | 'false';
sortValue:'arbitrary'|'furthest'|'nearest'|'random';

nameValue:NameValue;
fileReferrerValue:FileReferrerValue;
markValue:MarkValue;
typeValue:TypeValue;
intInterval:Int'..' | '..'Int | Int'..'Int;
decimalInterval: Decimal'..' | '..'Decimal | Decimal'..'Decimal;
gamemodeValue:'adventure' | 'creative' | 'spectator' | 'survival';
advancementsValue:'{'advancementPath '=' bool(','(advancementPath '=' bool)?)*'}';
scoresValue:'{'scorePath '=' intInterval(','(scorePath '=' intInterval)?)*'}';
```

Below is my C# main program script

```
using Antlr4.Runtime;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Misc;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Tree;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit;
using ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Document;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace LearnANTLR
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml 的交互逻辑
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Topmost = true;
        }
    }

    public class McfunctionIntellisense:ObservableObject
    {
        private string grammarFilePath = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/LearnANTLR;component/Grammar/mccommand.g4").LocalPath;
        private TextEditor textbox;
        private Window currentForm = null;
        AntlrInputStream inputStream = null;
        mccommandLexer lexer = null;
        CommonTokenStream tokenStream = null;
        selectorLexer selectorlexer = null;

        public McfunctionIntellisense()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 载入代码编辑器引用
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void TextBoxLoaded(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textbox = sender as TextEditor;
            currentForm = Window.GetWindow(textbox);
            currentForm.Topmost = false;
            textbox.Focus();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 代码编辑器键盘抬起预览事件
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public async void TextEditor_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            await IntellisenseService();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 提供语法补全服务
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task IntellisenseService()
        {
            await currentForm.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                int lineNumber = textbox.TextArea.Caret.Line;
                DocumentLine line = textbox.Document.GetLineByNumber(lineNumber);
                string lineText = textbox.Document.GetText(line.Offset, line.Length);
                currentForm.Title = lineText;

                //#region 创建主语法树的词法语法分析器
                //// 创建词法分析器
                inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(lineText);
                //lexer = new mccommandLexer(inputStream);
                //tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

                //// 创建语法分析器
                //mccommandParser parser = new mccommandParser(tokenStream);
                //// 重新执行语法分析器以获取更新后的上下文
                //parser.Reset();
                //mccommandParser.StatementContext context = parser.statement();
                //#endregion

                //#region mcf监听器
                //McfunctionListener mcfunctionListener = new McfunctionListener
                //{
                //    currentWindow = currentForm
                //};
                //mcfunctionListener.SetCursorOffset(textbox.TextArea.Caret.Offset);
                //ParseTreeWalker.Default.Walk(mcfunctionListener, context);
                //#endregion

                #region 选择器监听器
                SelectorListener selectorListener = new SelectorListener()
                {
                    currentWindow = currentForm
                };
                selectorListener.SetCursorOffset(textbox.TextArea.Caret.Offset);
                selectorLexer selectorlexer = new selectorLexer(inputStream);
                tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(selectorlexer);
                selectorParser selectorparser = new selectorParser(tokenStream);
                selectorParser.EntitySelectorContext entitySelectorContext = selectorparser.entitySelector();
                ParseTreeWalker.Default.Walk(selectorListener, entitySelectorContext);
                #endregion
            });
        }
    }

    // 创建自定义的监听器类，继承自 mccommandBaseListener
    public class McfunctionListener : mccommandBaseListener
    {
        public Window currentWindow = null;

        private int cursorOffset = 0;

        public void SetCursorOffset(int offset)
        {
            cursorOffset = offset - 1;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 处理通用的规则进入事件
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public override void EnterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext context)
        {
            if (context.Stop != null && context.Stop.StartIndex <= cursorOffset && context.Stop.StopIndex >= cursorOffset)
            {
                string title = context.Start.InputStream.GetText(Interval.Of(context.Stop.StartIndex, context.Stop.StopIndex));
                if (title.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (context is mccommandParser.SelectorContext || context is mccommandParser.OptionalSelectorContext)
                    {
                        #region 创建选择器的词法语法分析器
                        // 创建词法分析器
                        AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(title);
                        selectorLexer selectorlexer = new selectorLexer(inputStream);
                        CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(selectorlexer);

                        // 创建语法分析器
                        selectorParser selectorparser = new selectorParser(tokenStream);
                        // 重新执行语法分析器以获取更新后的上下文
                        selectorparser.Reset();
                        selectorParser.EntitySelectorContext selectorContext = selectorparser.entitySelector();
                        #endregion
                        #region 实体选择器监听器
                        SelectorListener selectorListener = new SelectorListener
                        {
                            currentWindow = currentWindow
                        };
                        selectorListener.SetCursorOffset(cursorOffset);
                        ParseTreeWalker.Default.Walk(selectorListener, selectorContext);
                        #endregion
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentWindow.Title = title + context.GetType().Name;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class SelectorListener : selectorBaseListener
    {
        public Window currentWindow = null;
        private int cursorOffset = 0;
        public void SetCursorOffset(int offset)
        {
            cursorOffset = offset - 1;
        }

        public override void EnterEveryRule([NotNull] ParserRuleContext context)
        {
            if (/*context.Stop != null && */context.Start.StartIndex <= cursorOffset && context.Start.StopIndex >= cursorOffset)
            {
                string title = context.Start.InputStream.GetText(Interval.Of(context.Start.StartIndex, context.Start.StopIndex));
                if (title.Length > 0)
                    currentWindow.Title = title + context.GetType().Name;
            }
        }

        public override void EnterSelectorType([NotNull] selectorParser.SelectorTypeContext context)
        {
            if (context.Stop != null && context.Stop.StartIndex <= cursorOffset && context.Stop.StopIndex >= cursorOffset)
            {
                string title = context.Start.InputStream.GetText(Interval.Of(context.Stop.StartIndex, context.Stop.StopIndex));
                if (title.Length > 0)
                    currentWindow.Title = title + context.GetType().Name;
            }
        }

        public override void EnterSelectorParameters([NotNull] selectorParser.SelectorParametersContext context)
        {
            if (/*context.Stop != null && */context.Start.StartIndex <= cursorOffset && context.Stop.StopIndex >= cursorOffset)
            {
                string title = context.Start.InputStream.GetText(Interval.Of(context.Start.StartIndex, context.Stop.StopIndex));
                if (title.Length > 0)
                    currentWindow.Title = title + context.GetType().Name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My current question is

When I type `@a[x=1]`, the cursor stays on the right side of x. At this time, the listener does not capture the context of `doubleKey`, but when I add a space to the right side of the opening bracket and move the cursor to the right side of x again After the side, the listener captured the `doubleKey` context, I would like to ask whether there is a problem with the content I wrote or is it a bug in the Antlr4.13 version?

This is the first time I have developed the auto-completion function of a custom language, so I don’t understand many places, I hope a guy can give me some pointers

> I have tried many ways including but not limited to

- Change the code of the listener to intercept what is typed in the text box
- Try to write different variants of selector parameter rules, such as promoting sub-rules to the position of parent rules, then executing cmd commands and finally turning on debugging